# Several questions about rijndael in .net

Tags: .net, encryption, rijndael

I need to consume a webservice exposed by another company.

They tell me to use Rijndael in OFB mode to encrypt the data I send them, but apparently, .Net (3.5) does not supports OFB for Rijndael. It tells me : `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: the (crypting?) mode is not valid for this algorithm` (approximate on-the-fly translation).

They gave me an IV that is 32 alphanumeric characters. I can't use it (using `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(k)`), it tells me : `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: the specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm` (approximate on-the-fly translation). The key is the same length as the IV, and it works.

What can I do to make it work ?

Thanks

Comment: 32-char IV = 256-bit IV, so make sure you use AES-256.

Comment: @Darhuuk: The size of the IV is the block size, not the key size, of the cipher. The 256 in AES-256 refers to the keysize. Probably the 32 chars are 32 ASCII hex digits that need to be decoded into a 16 byte IV.

Comment: @GregS Oh right, you're correct of course, I must have been dreaming when I typed that :).

Comment: @GregS : ok, but how do I decode the ASCII hex digits into a 16 byte IV ? Thanks

Comment: It is not too hard to write one yourself, or you can google for '.net hex decoder' to find various implementations.

Comment: I does not seems to be that : it translates into weird symbols. It looks more like a md5 hash of a string. Which is weird when I think about it, because I use the same method (md5 hash of a password) to generate my own IV in another part of the app, and it works fine. So why doesn't it works here ???

Answer (score 3):

You can use CBC mode to generate an OFB output by feeding your CBC method all 0s as plaintext input. Then manually xor the received keystream with your true plaintext. Actually, the diagrams on Wikipedia show quite nicely how this works, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output_feedback#Output_feedback_.28OFB.29).

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but I didn't understand any of it. I don't know much about encryption, I only know that the webservice provider asked us to encrypt the data using rijndael in OFB mode...

Comment: @cosmo0 Hm, well, it's kind of impossible to explain even the very basics of cryptography in a StackOverflow answer :). I suggest you study that Wikipedia page I linked very carefully, it gives a good overview of operation modes of block ciphers. Once you more or less get it, it should be possible to use the code you're given to construct OFB encrypted output.

Comment: @cosmo0 No, implementing crypto code yourself is generally a bad idea, since it's very easy to create subtle bugs. So far, I've managed to let other people worry about it :).

Comment: I know that, but in the meantime, I can't call our provider's webservice because their requirements cannot be met in .net :(